# Multitaper function in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, math, filter, spectrum

I'm searching a function in Python, which return the multitaper power spectral density, like pmtm for Matlab (http://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pmtm.html)

Anybody knows one ? I tried to install mtspec but without success on Python 3. Any other option ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [pmtm](http://pythonhosted.org/spectrum/ref_mtm.html?highlight=pmtm#spectrum.mtm.pmtm) from [spectrum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spectrum) which returns the multitapering spectral estimation

Install it using pip:

```
pip install spectrum
```

And use like the documentation example:

```
from spectrum import *

data = data_cosine(N=2048, A=0.1, sampling=1024, freq=200)
# If you already have the DPSS windows
[tapers, eigen] = dpss(2048, 2.5, 4)
res = pmtm(data, e=tapers, v=eigen, show=False)
# You do not need to compute the DPSS before end
res = pmtm(data, NW=2.5, show=False)
res = pmtm(data, NW=2.5, k=4, show=True)
```